# Polling two APIs in a single infinite for loop but with different delay

Tags: go, multiprocessing, polling

I have two APIs on a server. Let's say API A and API B. I want to call API A every 3 seconds and API B every 200 seconds. I have coded the program in the following structure:

1. Main: that handles authentication and handles API calls.
2. API-A: that calls API A and processes its data
3. API-B: that calls API B and processes its data.

Can anyone tell me how can I implement both of the API calls in a single program (Main). I am running a single for loop for API A with sleeping it for 3 seconds now I want to fit the API B with its condition of sleeping.

I want both of them to run simultaneously with their condition, while both be working in one program, main as it is handling authentication and I don't want to make two seperate programs for these two APIs.

Comment: All this is go-lang

Comment: goroutines can help you here.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up two timers and wait for events on both channels in a loop.

```
aTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 3)
bTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 200)
for {
  select {
    case <-aTicker.C:
      callApiA()
    case <-bTicker.C:
      callApiB()
  }
}
```